# ¿Como guardo un archivo XML con Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, xml

Estoy intentado guardar el archivo xml con laravel pero no lo logro

```
        $xml = new \DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

        $raiz = $xml->createElement('raiz');
        $raiz = $xml->appendChild($raiz);

        $nodo = $xml->createElement('Grafico');
        $nodo = $raiz->appendChild($nodo);

        $subnodo = $xml->createElement('item','texto dentro del item');
        $subnodo = $nodo->appendChild($subnodo);

        $xml->formatOutput = true;
        $xml->saveXML();
        $xml->save('albatros_Web/public/file_XML/archivo.xml');
```

Cuando intento guardar me aparece el siguiente error

> DOMDocument::save(albatros_Web/public/file_XML/): failed to open
>   stream: 
>       No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre la forma
Con simple XML

```
$xml = new \DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8'); //Se crea el docuemnto
```

//Se crea la raiz del elemento

```
$raiz = $xml->createElement('raiz');
$raiz = $xml->appendChild($raiz);
```

//Y se crean nodos anidados

```
$nodo_First = $xml->createElement('Grafico');
$nodo_First = $raiz->appendChild($nodo_First);

        /*---------------------------------------------inicio nodo_Second nodo de vector---------------------------------*/

        $nodo_Second = $xml->createElement('options');
        $nodo_Second = $nodo_First->appendChild($nodo_Second);

        /*---------------------------------------------Inicio nodo_Third nodo de atributo--------------------------------*/

        $nodo_Third = $xml->createElement('chart');
        $nodo_Third = $nodo_Second->appendChild($nodo_Third);

        $subnodo = $xml->createElement('type',$requestJSON[$i]->{'options'}->{'chart'}->{'type'}.'');
        $subnodo = $nodo_Third->appendChild($subnodo);
```

Al final

```
//Se eliminan espacios en blanco
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

//Se ingresa formato de salida
$xml->formatOutput = true;

//Se instancia el objeto
$xml_string =$xml->saveXML();

//Y se guarda en el nombre del archivo 'achivo.xml', y el obejto nstanciado
\Storage::disk('local')->put('archivo.xml',$xml_string);
```

Espero que esto le puedaservir a alguien